# Manage-scripts in an open-source program

Tags: bash, shell-script

**A strange thing happened when I try to use an open-source after GNU building , here it is :**

1. No error presents in ./configure ./make ./make install
2. When I try to use it , there is some vars in this manage scripts with no initialization value . This script is called "ionadmin" , and one of these NULL vars is , for example "NO_GLOB_SUBST" .
3. I can't find this name "NO_GLOB_SUBST" in the document . Otherwise , I can't find the assignment operation in root path by using this :

   find ~/ -type f |xargs grep 'NO_GLOB_SUBST'

**And there is the script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# ionadmin - temporary wrapper script for .libs/ionadmin
# Generated by libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2 Debian-2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1
#
# The ionadmin program cannot be directly executed until all the libtool
# libraries that it depends on are installed.
#
# This wrapper script should never be moved out of the build directory.
# If it is, it will not operate correctly.

# Sed substitution that helps us do robust quoting.  It backslashifies
# metacharacters that are still active within double-quoted strings.
sed_quote_subst='s/\([`"$\\]\)/\\\1/g'
echo "'++'${ZSH_VERSION+set}"
# Be Bourne compatible
if test -n "${ZSH_VERSION+set}" && (emulate sh) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  emulate sh
  NULLCMD=:
  # Zsh 3.x and 4.x performs word splitting on ${1+"$@"}, which
  # is contrary to our usage.  Disable this feature.
  alias -g '${1+"$@"}'='"$@"'
  setopt NO_GLOB_SUBST
else
  case `(set -o) 2>/dev/null` in *posix*) set -o posix;; esac
fi
BIN_SH=xpg4; export BIN_SH # for Tru64
DUALCASE=1; export DUALCASE # for MKS sh

# The HP-UX ksh and POSIX shell print the target directory to stdout
# if CDPATH is set.
(unset CDPATH) >/dev/null 2>&1 && unset CDPATH

relink_command="(cd /home/frankwang/ion-open-source; { test -z \"\${LIBRARY_PATH+set}\" || unset LIBRARY_PATH || { LIBRARY_PATH=; export LIBRARY_PATH; }; }; { test -z \"\${COMPILER_PATH+set}\" || unset COMPILER_PATH || { COMPILER_PATH=; export COMPILER_PATH; }; }; { test -z \"\${GCC_EXEC_PREFIX+set}\" || unset GCC_EXEC_PREFIX || { GCC_EXEC_PREFIX=; export GCC_EXEC_PREFIX; }; }; { test -z \"\${LD_RUN_PATH+set}\" || unset LD_RUN_PATH || { LD_RUN_PATH=; export LD_RUN_PATH; }; }; { test -z \"\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH+set}\" || unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH || { LD_LIBRARY_PATH=; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; }; }; PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin; export PATH; gcc -I./ici/library -I./bp/library -I./ltp/library -I./ici/test -I./ici/sdr -Dlinux -DSPACE_ORDER=3 -fno-strict-aliasing -DENABLE_BPACS -DENABLE_IMC -DENABLE_MANPAGES -Wall -Werror -g -include config.h -I./ici/include -I./ltp/include -I./dgr/include -I./bp/include -I./bss/include -I./dtpc/include -I./bssp/include -I./ams/include -I./cfdp/include -g -O2 -DNOEXPAT -o \$progdir/\$file ici/utils/ionadmin-ionadmin.o  -lpthread ./.libs/libici.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/frankwang/ion-open-source/.libs)"

# This environment variable determines our operation mode.
if test "$libtool_install_magic" = "%%%MAGIC variable%%%"; then
  # install mode needs the following variables:
  generated_by_libtool_version='2.4.2'
  notinst_deplibs=' libici.la'
else
  # When we are sourced in execute mode, $file and $ECHO are already set.
  if test "$libtool_execute_magic" != "%%%MAGIC variable%%%"; then
    file="$0"

# A function that is used when there is no print builtin or printf.
func_fallback_echo ()
{
  eval 'cat <<_LTECHO_EOF
$1
_LTECHO_EOF'
}
    ECHO="printf %s\\n"
  fi

# Very basic option parsing. These options are (a) specific to
# the libtool wrapper, (b) are identical between the wrapper
# /script/ and the wrapper /executable/ which is used only on
# windows platforms, and (c) all begin with the string --lt-
# (application programs are unlikely to have options which match
# this pattern).
#
# There are only two supported options: --lt-debug and
# --lt-dump-script. There is, deliberately, no --lt-help.
#
# The first argument to this parsing function should be the
# script's ./libtool value, followed by no.
lt_option_debug=
func_parse_lt_options ()
{
  lt_script_arg0=$0
  shift
  for lt_opt
  do
    case "$lt_opt" in
    --lt-debug) lt_option_debug=1 ;;
    --lt-dump-script)
        lt_dump_D=`$ECHO "X$lt_script_arg0" | /bin/sed -e 's/^X//' -e 's%/[^/]*$%%'`
        test "X$lt_dump_D" = "X$lt_script_arg0" && lt_dump_D=.
        lt_dump_F=`$ECHO "X$lt_script_arg0" | /bin/sed -e 's/^X//' -e 's%^.*/%%'`
        cat "$lt_dump_D/$lt_dump_F"
        exit 0
      ;;
    --lt-*)
        $ECHO "Unrecognized --lt- option: '$lt_opt'" 1>&2
        exit 1
      ;;
    esac
  done

  # Print the debug banner immediately:
  if test -n "$lt_option_debug"; then
    echo "ionadmin:ionadmin:${LINENO}: libtool wrapper (GNU libtool) 2.4.2 Debian-2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1" 1>&2
  fi
}

# Used when --lt-debug. Prints its arguments to stdout
# (redirection is the responsibility of the caller)
func_lt_dump_args ()
{
  lt_dump_args_N=1;
  for lt_arg
  do
    $ECHO "ionadmin:ionadmin:${LINENO}: newargv[$lt_dump_args_N]: $lt_arg"
    lt_dump_args_N=`expr $lt_dump_args_N + 1`
  done
}

# Core function for launching the target application
func_exec_program_core ()
{

      if test -n "$lt_option_debug"; then
        $ECHO "ionadmin:ionadmin:${LINENO}: newargv[0]: $progdir/$program" 1>&2
        func_lt_dump_args ${1+"$@"} 1>&2
      fi
      exec "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}

      $ECHO "$0: cannot exec $program $*" 1>&2
      exit 1
}

# A function to encapsulate launching the target application
# Strips options in the --lt-* namespace from $@ and
# launches target application with the remaining arguments.
func_exec_program ()
{
  case " $* " in
  *\ --lt-*)
    for lt_wr_arg
    do
      case $lt_wr_arg in
      --lt-*) ;;
      *) set x "$@" "$lt_wr_arg"; shift;;
      esac
      shift
    done ;;
  esac
  func_exec_program_core ${1+"$@"}
}

  # Parse options
  func_parse_lt_options "$0" ${1+"$@"}

  # Find the directory that this script lives in.
  thisdir=`$ECHO "$file" | /bin/sed 's%/[^/]*$%%'`
  test "x$thisdir" = "x$file" && thisdir=.

  # Follow symbolic links until we get to the real thisdir.
  file=`ls -ld "$file" | /bin/sed -n 's/.*-> //p'`
  while test -n "$file"; do
    destdir=`$ECHO "$file" | /bin/sed 's%/[^/]*$%%'`

    # If there was a directory component, then change thisdir.
    if test "x$destdir" != "x$file"; then
      case "$destdir" in
      [\\/]* | [A-Za-z]:[\\/]*) thisdir="$destdir" ;;
      *) thisdir="$thisdir/$destdir" ;;
      esac
    fi

    file=`$ECHO "$file" | /bin/sed 's%^.*/%%'`
    file=`ls -ld "$thisdir/$file" | /bin/sed -n 's/.*-> //p'`
  done

  # Usually 'no', except on cygwin/mingw when embedded into
  # the cwrapper.
  WRAPPER_SCRIPT_BELONGS_IN_OBJDIR=no
  if test "$WRAPPER_SCRIPT_BELONGS_IN_OBJDIR" = "yes"; then
    # special case for '.'
    if test "$thisdir" = "."; then
      thisdir=`pwd`
    fi
    # remove .libs from thisdir
    case "$thisdir" in
    *[\\/].libs ) thisdir=`$ECHO "$thisdir" | /bin/sed 's%[\\/][^\\/]*$%%'` ;;
    .libs )   thisdir=. ;;
    esac
  fi

  # Try to get the absolute directory name.
  absdir=`cd "$thisdir" && pwd`
  test -n "$absdir" && thisdir="$absdir"

  program=lt-'ionadmin'
  progdir="$thisdir/.libs"

  if test ! -f "$progdir/$program" ||
     { file=`ls -1dt "$progdir/$program" "$progdir/../$program" 2>/dev/null | /bin/sed 1q`; \
       test "X$file" != "X$progdir/$program"; }; then

    file="$$-$program"

    if test ! -d "$progdir"; then
      mkdir "$progdir"
    else
      rm -f "$progdir/$file"
    fi

    # relink executable if necessary
    if test -n "$relink_command"; then
      if relink_command_output=`eval $relink_command 2>&1`; then :
      else
    printf %s\n "$relink_command_output" >&2
    rm -f "$progdir/$file"
    exit 1
      fi
    fi

    mv -f "$progdir/$file" "$progdir/$program" 2>/dev/null ||
    { rm -f "$progdir/$program";
      mv -f "$progdir/$file" "$progdir/$program"; }
    rm -f "$progdir/$file"
  fi

  if test -f "$progdir/$program"; then
    if test "$libtool_execute_magic" != "%%%MAGIC variable%%%"; then
      # Run the actual program with our arguments.
      func_exec_program ${1+"$@"}
    fi
  else
    # The program doesn't exist.
    $ECHO "$0: error: \`$progdir/$program' does not exist" 1>&2
    $ECHO "This script is just a wrapper for $program." 1>&2
    $ECHO "See the libtool documentation for more information." 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

**So , here is my question :**
To what condition , do the author of this script use these vars not initialized ? 
Or , there is some mistake I ignored ?
there is another question I have posted : [CLICK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239503/debug-an-open-source-and-be-confronted-with-some-troubles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686888/something-confused-in-a-admin-scipts), and it was noted that `NO_GLOB_SUBST` is a zsh keyword (see [options index](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options-Index.html)).  That [links](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NO_005fGLOB_005fSUBST) to

> **`GLOB_SUBST`** `<C> <K> <S>`
>
> Treat any characters resulting from parameter expansion as being eligible for filename expansion and filename generation, and any characters resulting from command substitution as being eligible for filename generation. Braces (and commas in between) do not become eligible for expansion.

So... "`NO_`" in front turns that feature **off**.

Without a dollar-sign (`$`) in front of the name, neither zsh nor bash would treat that as a *variable* rather than as a *name* or *keyword*.